# mysql addtime() appears not to work for large times (many days)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from data order by poll_time desc limit 10;
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| server_id | poll_time           | oid_id | value     | value_interval |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    268 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    267 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    266 |        43 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    265 |     21765 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    263 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    262 |   2560190 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    261 | 204851561 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    260 |  29941762 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    258 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-09-23 20:10:00 |    257 |         0 |              0 |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `data` 
       SET `poll_time` = ADDTIME(`poll_time`, '38 00:00:00') 
       ORDER BY `poll_time` DESC;

Query OK, 168700 rows affected, 65535 warnings (30.63 sec)
Rows matched: 168700  Changed: 168700  Warnings: 168700

mysql> select * from data order by poll_time desc limit 10;
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| server_id | poll_time           | oid_id | value     | value_interval |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    268 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    267 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    266 |        43 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    265 |     21765 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    263 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    262 |   2560190 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    261 | 204851561 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    260 |  29941762 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    258 |         0 |              0 |
|         2 | 2014-10-28 19:09:59 |    257 |         0 |              0 |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

By my count, 38 days should take us to 10/31, not 10/28.

I realize there's an `ADDDATE()` function, but this is being run from a script, so I was hoping for a mechanism that could add either a date or a time equally well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug in mysql.

see [BUG 25620](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25620)
and [BUG 11655](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11655)
the issue is with a time value greater than `838:59:59` it gets truncated to that value. addtime converts a time with number of days to a time portion. and up to 35 days is within that time portion.

you should use [**date_add()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) as it will only update the date portion and leave the time segment the same

```
SELECT 
  poll_time, 
  date_add(`poll_time`, INTERVAL 38 DAY) 
FROM data
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e529a/1)

```
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|            POLL_TIME             | DATE_ADD(`POLL_TIME`, INTERVAL 38 DAY) |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
| September, 23 2014 20:10:00+0000 | October, 31 2014 20:10:00+0000         |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

## EDIT:

on further research it looks like this is the expected behavior. as Mysql has limits set on the time being that large. anything further than that should be a date calculation. [**DOCS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time.html)

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) function instead and you will get what you want.

Proof:

```
mysql> select date_add('2014-09-23 20:10:00', INTERVAL 38 DAY);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| date_add('2014-09-23 20:10:00', INTERVAL 38 DAY) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-31 20:10:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```